# create new variables based on other variables, with a loop over variables names in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataset with variables named as I10AA to I10ZZ and I11AA to I11ZZ. I want to create new variables IAA to IZZ, so that IAA = function(I10AA,I11AA).

As an highly simplified example.

```
set.seed(0)

df <- data.frame(I10AA=floor(runif(10,1,5)),I10AB=floor(runif(10,1,5)),
             I11AA=floor(runif(10,1,5)),I11AB=floor(runif(10,1,5)))

fun <- function(x,y) (x+y)

results <- df %>% mutate(IAA = fun(I10AA,I11AA),IAB = fun(I10AB,I11AB))

print(results)
```

results is the final dataset I want.

Is there a way to do this with tidyverse?

In the original dataset, the variables are arranged as:

```
 colnames(original_data) = "ID","I1AA", "I1AB", "I1AC", ... , "I1ZZ", "I2AA","I2AB",...,"I2ZZ",...,"I10AA",...,"I10ZZ","I11AA",..."I11ZZ"
```

Comment: Can you tell us how the columns are arranged in the orignial dataset?

Comment: There is no issue with the function, but I do not know how to loop over I10AA to I11ZZ

Comment: Of course. Edited.

Comment: Please check the solution posted. It should work

Comment: I really like the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop through the column names, use `transmute` to create new columns, rename the columns with the substring of the column names and bind with the original data

```
library(tidyverse)
i1 <- grepl("10", names(df))
nm1 <- sub("\\d+", "", names(df)[i1])
i2 <- !i1

map2(names(df)[i1], names(df)[i2], ~
        df %>% 
          transmute(fun(!! rlang::sym(.x), !!rlang::sym(.y)))) %>% 
          bind_cols %>% 
          rename_all(., ~ nm1) %>%
  bind_cols(df, .)
#    I10AA I10AB I11AA I11AB IAA IAB
#1      4     1     4     2   8   3
#2      2     1     4     2   6   3
#3      2     1     1     3   3   4
#4      3     3     3     2   6   5
#5      4     2     1     1   5   3
#6      1     4     2     4   3   8
#7      4     2     2     3   6   5
#8      4     3     1     4   5   7
#9      3     4     2     1   5   5
#10     3     2     4     3   7   5
```

Or another option is to create place the subset of datasets in a `list` and use `reduce` to pass the `+`

```
list(df %>% 
        select(names(.)[i1]),
     df %>%
        select(names(.)[i2])) %>% 
  reduce(`+`) %>% 
  rename_all(., ~ nm1) %>% 
  bind_cols(df, .)
```

---

An easier option would be

```
df[nm1] <- df[i1] + df[i2]
```